# Error: Deleted images of a Docker container

Tags: image, docker, containers, commit

I had three docker containers and lots of images, so I decided deleting some of them and I deleted all the images accidentally. Now, I can't make "commit" and I get this error message: "Error response from daemon: failed to get digest 
sha256:67238b4c1da06cdaec89d5728aaaa72b762304bffcc45b6bd7110503c9528111: open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/67238b4c1da06cdaec89d5728aaaa72b762304bffcc45b6bd7110503c9528111: no such file or directory".

If I write: "docker images" it doesn't show anyone.

Here you can see the console. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xEVQ.png)

Any idea, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Restore your backup? If you have none, have you tried to pull the images again? See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/ and note the “Pull an image by digest“ variant too.

Comment: I think it's a problem of Docker layers. Multi images would share the same layer. If you delete one image it maybe affects others. So I suggest you could try to pull the images that you would use again. Maybe it's helpful.

Comment: When I've had Docker get confused in this way before, I've found it helps to stop the Docker daemon, delete everything in `/var/lib/docker`, and start again.  This means you need to rebuild your images with `docker build`...and it's a key reason to never use `docker commit`.